# How can I submit an App to MyApps that is already in a PPA?

Tags: application-development, ppa

All my applications are already in my PPA in Launchpad. Now I want to submit them to [MyApps](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/). But MyApps insists in getting something to upload which makes no sense because everything is already uploaded and confirmed in my PPA. I put the information about the PPA in the 'additional notes for the reviewer'. Please help me to proceed.

Comment: For those that weren't sure what MyApps is, see: https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/

Answer (score 3):

It is great you already have your App in Launchpad, this makes lots of things easier.

We do require an upload, however if you want to submit via a ppa just upload a  text file that with a http reference to the ppa). The reviewer will see it (and see your feedback) and review the details in the ppa. We do plan to add the ability to simply reference a launchpad ppa in the future.

Second is your App Open Source software and have you read the publishing guidelines for the Open Source review process by the App Review Board (ARB)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard

Comment: Ok, I can submit a dummy file. I don't understand what you mean with 'ARB' and '/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/'. I would just like to benefit from the extra pieces that MyApps gives me like a screenshot of the application which I never managed to bring into Software-Center the 'old-school' way. But I want to avoid that anybody breaks my existing PPA.

Comment: Application Review Board. The PPA will be entirely independent of the application in the software center. So you can keep developing and using the PPA for testing or more unstable versions, and when you have something solid, you send it in. Good question by the way.